# Further Probing in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so i'm pretty new to BeautifulSoup and web scraping in general. I am currently running the code:

```
attraction_names_full = soup.find_all('td', class_='alt2', align = 'right', height = '28')
```

Which is returning a list comprising of objects which look like this:

```
<td align="right" class="alt2" height="28">
 A Pirate's Adventure - Treasures of the Seven Seas
 <br/>
 <span style="font-size: 9px; color: #627DAD; font-style: italic;">
  12:00pm to 6:00pm
 </span>
</td>
```

What I am trying to get from this is just the line containing the text, which in this case would be

```
A Pirate's Adventure - Treasures of the Seven Seas
```

however I'm not sure how to go about this as it doesn't seem to have any tags surrounding just the text.

I have attempted to see if I can interact with the elements as strings however the object type seems to be:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

Which i'm not sure how to manipulate and am sure there must be a much more efficient way of achieving this.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? - For reference the webpage i'm looking at is

```
url = 'https://www.thedibb.co.uk/forums/wait_times.php?a=MK'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.thedibb.co.uk/forums/wait_times.php?a=MK").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
listElem = list(soup.find_all('td', class_='alt2', align = 'right', height = '28'))
print(listElem[1].contents[0])
```

You can use .contents , it works for me, the output is "Captain Jack Sparrow's Pirate Tutorial"

Comment: Note: Do not use `list` as a variable name. It overwrites the Python `list()` command.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the `<span>` element and then get the stripped text as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://www.thedibb.co.uk/forums/wait_times.php?a=MK').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for attraction in soup.find_all('td', class_='alt2', align='right', height='28'):
    attraction.span.extract()
    print attraction.get_text(strip=True)
```

Which would give you output starting:

```
A Pirate's Adventure - Treasures of the Seven Seas
Captain Jack Sparrow's Pirate Tutorial
Jungle Cruise
Meet Characters from Aladdin in Adventureland
Pirates of the Caribbean
Swiss Family Treehouse
```